# PHP/JS use use templates to create PDF and doc/docx/otf files

Tags: javascript, php, html, templates, pdf

Hello as I am dyslexia my text writing skills are not the best, so please bear with me.

I have a problem that I am kind of stuck on.

I have a form on a webpage where a user fills in their details and clicks submit, after that a mail is being sent with a PDF as an attachment to my email. ATM. I am using JsPDF to create the PDF, and that is working fine.

But I now need to create both a PDF and docx/doc(Or some other word compatible file) that is easily editable, so that it is possible to make minor changes before forwarding the document to a 3. party. (Could be  for extra personalization of the text)

It is important that it is easy to edit the template for nonskilled coders (Where JsPDF is on the heavy site)

I have without luck tried to find a solution that could use a word file as a template and fill in the users first name, last name, etc. but without luck.

Anyone, who has any idea about how to solve this?

Requirements:
* Opensource/Freeware/onetime payment
** Usable on multiple domains (PHPDOCX is out of my price range)
* Support for custom fonts
* Support for special characters like the Danish "ÆØÅ."
* No installs required on the server, other than PHP (5 or 7), Javascript and HTML.
* The PDF and docx/doc need to be equal in the layout.
* Easy template creation and maintenance (preferable though either plain HTML or word 2016+)
* Support for Images in the template

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have looked a bit on PHPWord but I was not able to see any examples of editing existing files, did I miss it?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/0459670a9c0517872f513a484eae36285c6239b4/samples/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.php#L9 - look at the code then look at the template https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/resources/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx as you can see the variables get filled with the data.

Answer (score 0):

@Laswrence was right PHPWORD does solve my problem, as I can install the composer on my DEV pc get all dependencies and then upload everything to the server.

The only thing that I am not sure about yet is how to get the PDF part to work as there are some issues with PHPWORD and PDF.